# Provide way to filter out synonyms tags on tags page

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would like to have a way to filter-out synonyms tags on Tags page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags.

I think it could be useful if one wants to browse tags by popularity from lower to higher. Then we can navigate to last page. Currently, navigating to last page we end up with a series of tags which are marked as having zero questions but are actually synonyms.